# How can I send SPARQL queries via curl (over HTTP) to Openlink Virtuoso and obtain the results in JSON

Tags: virtuoso, openlink-virtuoso

I am looking for extensive `sparql-graph-crud` documentation or other mechanism which details how to submit queries to Openlink Virtuoso SPARQL endpoint.

In short, I would like to learn how to send SPARQL queries (with `WHERE` clauses) via `curl` (over HTTP) to Openlink Virtuoso and obtain the results in JSON.

For example, I would like to submit a query such as `SELECT * FROM <http://www.example.com/ABC> where { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 100` to Openlink Virtuoso at `localhost`.

The example (below) provided on the OpenLink Virtuoso page is not sufficient for my queries.

> `curl --verbose --url "http://localhost:8890/sparql-graph-crud?graph-uri=urn:graph:update:test:post"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [described in the Virtuoso documentation](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlprotocolendpoint/), the `/sparql-graph-crud` endpoint is meant specifically for the [SPARQL 1.1 Graph Store HTTP Protocol](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-http-rdf-update/).  If you just want to execute `SELECT` queries like your sample, you can simply use the `/sparql` endpoint, with `&query=` plus a URI-escaped string of your query, and `&format=application/rdf+json` in the URI to get results as JSON.

It can be instructional to use your Virtuoso `/sparql` query form in your web browser (i.e., http://localhost:8890/sparql) to submit your query requesting default (HTML) output, and then adjust the resulting URI just by changing the `&format=` argument, as --

> `curl --verbose --url "http://localhost:8890/sparql-graph-crud?default-graph-uri=&query=SELECT+*+FROM+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2FABC%3E+where+%7B+%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo+%7D+LIMIT+100&format=application/rdf+json&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+"`

Also note that you can load [the above URI, having changed only the `&query=` to `&qtxt=`, to see the whole form filled out in your browser](http://localhost:8890/sparql-graph-crud?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2FABC%3E%20where%20%7B%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%7D%20LIMIT%20100&format=application/rdf%20json&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20).

For quite extensive documentation, there are the [Virtuoso website](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com) and [Virtuoso product manual](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/).

The [OpenLink Community Forum](http://community.openlinksw.com) and [Virtuoso Users mailing list](http://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/) are also good places to find folks (including many Virtuoso developers) who are particularly knowledgeable about Virtuoso.

Comment: thank you for your answer and advise on using /sparql. I have composed a solution using /sparql as advised that works. I will be posting it shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Following [advice from @TallTed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56838161/241164), I have composed the following solution.

```
date;time curl -X POST "http://localhost:8890/sparql" \
   -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
   -H "Accept:application/sparql-results+json" \
   --data-urlencode 'format=json' \
   --data-urlencode 'default-graph-uri=http://www.example.com/ABC' \
   --data-urlencode 'query=SELECT * FROM <http://www.example.com/ABC> WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 5' \
   --write-out '%{url_effective};%{http_code};%{time_total};%{time_namelookup};%{time_connect};%{size_download};%{speed_download}\n';date;
```